# Xfce4 & make dcript for saving theme in a script for restore theme

Tags: bash, themes, command-line-interface, xfce, mate

I'm trying to write a Script for save all desktop theme cursors, icons, fonts, wallpapers, panel + panel Content.

This is very simple and repetitive script. Becuase I don't know a better method for saving and using variables with some more advance in Bash.

Here is my current script:

```
#!/bin/sh
#!/bin/bash
#
# Autor :   Inukaze ( Venezuela )
# Sitio     :   http://inukaze.wordpResolucions.com
# Correo-E  :   inukaze.otaku@gmail.com
# Licensia  :   GPL 2
#
# Acerca de este Script :
#
# Es para cambiar con mayor comodidad tu
# Tema de Escritorio , me refiero a cambiar :
#
# Motor(es) / Controles / Botones
# Cursores
# Iconos
# Fuentes
# Papel Tapiz / Fondo de Pantalla
#
# Primero que nada guardando un respaldo
# de tu tema actual en uso , en caso de que
# no te guste , puedas restaurarlo comodamente
#
#

# Detectar Escritorio en uso :
DIR=(pwd)
MATE=$(ps -A                |   grep mate-session       |   awk '{print $4}')
XFCE=$(ps -A            |   grep xfce-session       |   awk '{print $4}')
XFCE4=$(ps -A           |   grep xfce4-session      |   awk '{print $4}')
xfconf_query=$(whereis -B "/usr/sbin" "/usr/local/sbin" "/sbin" "/usr/bin" "/usr/local/bin" "/bin" -b xfconf-query | grep -i "xfconf-query" | cut -d " " -f02)

# Guardar la Resolución En caso de querer Aplicar
# un Fondo de Pantalla para para la resolución Actual
# en caso de tener varios

# Guardar - Resolución :
echo `xrandr --current | grep current | awk '{print $8}'` >> Resolucion1
echo `xrandr --current | grep current | awk '{print $10}'` >> Resolucion2
cat Resolucion2 | sed -i 's/,//g' Resolucion2
P1Resolucion=$(cat Resolucion1)
P2Resolucion=$(cat Resolucion2)
rm Resolucion1 Resolucion2
echo "$P1Resolucion"'x'"$P2Resolucion" >> Resolucion
Resolucion=$(cat Resolucion)
rm Resolucion
# Guardar - Resolución .



if [ "$XFCE" = "xfce-session" ]; then
# Si se detecta xfce-session en ejecucion
# Primero determinar si "xfconf-query"
# esta instalado
#
# Intentar guardar las variables actuales
# de :
#
# Motor(es) / Controles / Botones / Tema GTK
# Gestor de Ventanas : Si es Xfwm/4 , detectar el tema en uso.
# Cursores
# Iconos
# Fuentes
# Papel Tapiz / Fondo de Pantalla
# Panel(es)


# Obtener :

# Motor(es) / Controles / Botones / Tema GTK
# Canal : xfsettings ; Propiedad 1 : /Net/ThemeName
    #xfconf-query -c xsettings -p /Net/ThemeName -l -v  
    #Controles=$(xfconf-query -c xsettings -p /Net/ThemeName -l -v | awk -F'/' '/^/ { print $3 }' | sed 's/[ThemeName]*.//')
     Controles=$(xfconf-query -c xsettings -p /Net/ThemeName)

# Gestor de Ventanas :
# Tema : Xfwm(4)
    #xfconf-query -c xfwm4 -p /general/theme -l -v
    #Tema_Xfwm4=$(xfconf-query -c xfwm4 -p /general/theme -l -v | awk -F'/' '/^/ { print $3 }' | sed 's/[theme]*.//')
     Tema_Xfwm4=$(xfconf-query -c xfwm4 -p /general/theme)

# Cursores :    
# Tema de Cursor(es)
    #xfconf-query -c xsettings -p /Gtk/CursorThemeName -l -v
    #Tema_Cursores=$(xfconf-query -c xsettings -p /Gtk/CursorThemeName -l -v | awk -F'/' '/^/ { print $3 }' | sed 's/[CursorThemeName]*.//')
     Tema_Cursores=$(xfconf-query -c xsettings -p /Gtk/CursorThemeName)

# Tamaño de (el/los) Cursor(es)
    #xfconf-query -c xsettings -p /Gtk/CursorThemeSize -l -v
    #Tamano_Cursores=$(xfconf-query -c xsettings -p /Gtk/CursorThemeSize -l -v | awk -F'/' '/^/ { print $3 }' | sed 's/[CursorThemeSize]*.//')
     Tamano_Cursores=$(xfconf-query -c xsettings -p /Gtk/CursorThemeSize)

# Iconos :
# Tema de Iconos Actual :
    #xfconf-query -c xsettings -p /Net/IconThemeName -l -v
    #Tema_Iconos=$(xfconf-query -c xsettings -p /Net/IconThemeName -l -v | awk -F'/' '/^/ { print $3 }' | sed 's/[IconThemeName]*.//')
     Tema_Iconos=$(xfconf-query -c xsettings -p /Net/IconThemeName)

# Fuente :
# Nombre de la Fuente + Tamaño de la Fuente
#xfconf-query -c xsettings -p /Gtk/FontName -l -v
    #Fuente=$(xfconf-query -c xsettings -p /Gtk/FontName -l -v | awk -F'/' '/^/ { print $3 }' | sed 's/[FontName]*.//')
     Fuente=$(xfconf-query -c xsettings -p /Gtk/FontName)

# Papel Tapiz / Fondo de Pantalla
# xfconf-query -c xfce4-desktop -p /backdrop/screen{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9}/monitor{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9}/image-path -l -v

    FP0M0=$(xfconf-query -c xfce4-desktop -p /backdrop/screen0/monitor0/image-path)
    FP0M1=$(xfconf-query -c xfce4-desktop -p /backdrop/screen0/monitor1/image-path)
    FP0M2=$(xfconf-query -c xfce4-desktop -p /backdrop/screen0/monitor2/image-path)
    FP0M3=$(xfconf-query -c xfce4-desktop -p /backdrop/screen0/monitor3/image-path)
    FP0M4=$(xfconf-query -c xfce4-desktop -p /backdrop/screen0/monitor4/image-path)
    FP0M5=$(xfconf-query -c xfce4-desktop -p /backdrop/screen0/monitor5/image-path) 
    FP0M6=$(xfconf-query -c xfce4-desktop -p /backdrop/screen0/monitor6/image-path)
    FP0M7=$(xfconf-query -c xfce4-desktop -p /backdrop/screen0/monitor7/image-path)
    FP0M8=$(xfconf-query -c xfce4-desktop -p /backdrop/screen0/monitor8/image-path)
    FP0M9=$(xfconf-query -c xfce4-desktop -p /backdrop/screen0/monitor9/image-path) 
    FP1M0=$(xfconf-query -c xfce4-desktop -p /backdrop/screen1/monitor0/image-path)
    FP1M1=$(xfconf-query -c xfce4-desktop -p /backdrop/screen1/monitor1/image-path)
    FP1M2=$(xfconf-query -c xfce4-desktop -p /backdrop/screen1/monitor2/image-path)
    FP1M3=$(xfconf-query -c xfce4-desktop -p /backdrop/screen1/monitor3/image-path)
    FP1M4=$(xfconf-query -c xfce4-desktop -p /backdrop/screen1/monitor4/image-path)
    FP1M5=$(xfconf-query -c xfce4-desktop -p /backdrop/screen1/monitor5/image-path)
    FP1M6=$(xfconf-query -c xfce4-desktop -p /backdrop/screen1/monitor6/image-path)
    FP1M7=$(xfconf-query -c xfce4-desktop -p /backdrop/screen1/monitor7/image-path)
    FP1M8=$(xfconf-query -c xfce4-desktop -p /backdrop/screen1/monitor8/image-path)
    FP1M9=$(xfconf-query -c xfce4-desktop -p /backdrop/screen1/monitor9/image-path)
    FP2M0=$(xfconf-query -c xfce4-desktop -p /backdrop/screen2/monitor0/image-path)
    FP2M1=$(xfconf-query -c xfce4-desktop -p /backdrop/screen2/monitor1/image-path)
    FP2M2=$(xfconf-query -c xfce4-desktop -p /backdrop/screen2/monitor2/image-path)
    FP2M3=$(xfconf-query -c xfce4-desktop -p /backdrop/screen2/monitor3/image-path)
    FP2M4=$(xfconf-query -c xfce4-desktop -p /backdrop/screen2/monitor4/image-path)
    FP2M5=$(xfconf-query -c xfce4-desktop -p /backdrop/screen2/monitor5/image-path) 
    FP2M6=$(xfconf-query -c xfce4-desktop -p /backdrop/screen2/monitor6/image-path)
    FP2M7=$(xfconf-query -c xfce4-desktop -p /backdrop/screen2/monitor7/image-path)
    FP2M8=$(xfconf-query -c xfce4-desktop -p /backdrop/screen2/monitor8/image-path)
    FP2M9=$(xfconf-query -c xfce4-desktop -p /backdrop/screen2/monitor9/image-path) 
    FP3M0=$(xfconf-query -c xfce4-desktop -p /backdrop/screen3/monitor0/image-path)
    FP3M1=$(xfconf-query -c xfce4-desktop -p /backdrop/screen3/monitor1/image-path)
    FP3M2=$(xfconf-query -c xfce4-desktop -p /backdrop/screen3/monitor2/image-path)
    FP3M3=$(xfconf-query -c xfce4-desktop -p /backdrop/screen3/monitor3/image-path)
    FP3M4=$(xfconf-query -c xfce4-desktop -p /backdrop/screen3/monitor4/image-path)
    FP3M5=$(xfconf-query -c xfce4-desktop -p /backdrop/screen3/monitor5/image-path) 
    FP3M6=$(xfconf-query -c xfce4-desktop -p /backdrop/screen3/monitor6/image-path)
    FP3M7=$(xfconf-query -c xfce4-desktop -p /backdrop/screen3/monitor7/image-path)
    FP3M8=$(xfconf-query -c xfce4-desktop -p /backdrop/screen3/monitor8/image-path)
    FP3M9=$(xfconf-query -c xfce4-desktop -p /backdrop/screen3/monitor9/image-path) 
    FP4M0=$(xfconf-query -c xfce4-desktop -p /backdrop/screen4/monitor0/image-path)
    FP4M1=$(xfconf-query -c xfce4-desktop -p /backdrop/screen4/monitor1/image-path)
    FP4M2=$(xfconf-query -c xfce4-desktop -p /backdrop/screen4/monitor2/image-path)
    FP4M3=$(xfconf-query -c xfce4-desktop -p /backdrop/screen4/monitor3/image-path)
    FP4M4=$(xfconf-query -c xfce4-desktop -p /backdrop/screen4/monitor4/image-path)
    FP4M5=$(xfconf-query -c xfce4-desktop -p /backdrop/screen4/monitor5/image-path) 
    FP4M6=$(xfconf-query -c xfce4-desktop -p /backdrop/screen4/monitor6/image-path)
    FP4M7=$(xfconf-query -c xfce4-desktop -p /backdrop/screen4/monitor7/image-path)
    FP4M8=$(xfconf-query -c xfce4-desktop -p /backdrop/screen4/monitor8/image-path)
    FP4M9=$(xfconf-query -c xfce4-desktop -p /backdrop/screen4/monitor9/image-path) 
    FP5M0=$(xfconf-query -c xfce4-desktop -p /backdrop/screen5/monitor0/image-path)
    FP5M1=$(xfconf-query -c xfce4-desktop -p /backdrop/screen5/monitor1/image-path)
    FP5M2=$(xfconf-query -c xfce4-desktop -p /backdrop/screen5/monitor2/image-path)
    FP5M3=$(xfconf-query -c xfce4-desktop -p /backdrop/screen5/monitor3/image-path)
    FP5M4=$(xfconf-query -c xfce4-desktop -p /backdrop/screen5/monitor4/image-path)
    FP5M5=$(xfconf-query -c xfce4-desktop -p /backdrop/screen5/monitor5/image-path) 
    FP5M6=$(xfconf-query -c xfce4-desktop -p /backdrop/screen5/monitor6/image-path)
    FP5M7=$(xfconf-query -c xfce4-desktop -p /backdrop/screen5/monitor7/image-path)
    FP5M8=$(xfconf-query -c xfce4-desktop -p /backdrop/screen5/monitor8/image-path)
    FP5M9=$(xfconf-query -c xfce4-desktop -p /backdrop/screen5/monitor9/image-path) 
    FP6M0=$(xfconf-query -c xfce4-desktop -p /backdrop/screen6/monitor0/image-path)
    FP6M1=$(xfconf-query -c xfce4-desktop -p /backdrop/screen6/monitor1/image-path)
    FP6M2=$(xfconf-query -c xfce4-desktop -p /backdrop/screen6/monitor2/image-path)
    FP6M3=$(xfconf-query -c xfce4-desktop -p /backdrop/screen6/monitor3/image-path)
    FP6M4=$(xfconf-query -c xfce4-desktop -p /backdrop/screen6/monitor4/image-path)
    FP6M5=$(xfconf-query -c xfce4-desktop -p /backdrop/screen6/monitor5/image-path) 
    FP6M6=$(xfconf-query -c xfce4-desktop -p /backdrop/screen6/monitor6/image-path)
    FP6M7=$(xfconf-query -c xfce4-desktop -p /backdrop/screen6/monitor7/image-path)
    FP6M8=$(xfconf-query -c xfce4-desktop -p /backdrop/screen6/monitor8/image-path)
    FP6M9=$(xfconf-query -c xfce4-desktop -p /backdrop/screen6/monitor9/image-path) 
    FP7M0=$(xfconf-query -c xfce4-desktop -p /backdrop/screen7/monitor0/image-path)
    FP7M1=$(xfconf-query -c xfce4-desktop -p /backdrop/screen7/monitor1/image-path)
    FP7M2=$(xfconf-query -c xfce4-desktop -p /backdrop/screen7/monitor2/image-path)
    FP7M3=$(xfconf-query -c xfce4-desktop -p /backdrop/screen7/monitor3/image-path)
    FP7M4=$(xfconf-query -c xfce4-desktop -p /backdrop/screen7/monitor4/image-path)
    FP7M5=$(xfconf-query -c xfce4-desktop -p /backdrop/screen7/monitor5/image-path) 
    FP7M6=$(xfconf-query -c xfce4-desktop -p /backdrop/screen7/monitor6/image-path)
    FP7M7=$(xfconf-query -c xfce4-desktop -p /backdrop/screen7/monitor7/image-path)
    FP7M8=$(xfconf-query -c xfce4-desktop -p /backdrop/screen7/monitor8/image-path)
    FP7M9=$(xfconf-query -c xfce4-desktop -p /backdrop/screen7/monitor9/image-path) 
    FP8M0=$(xfconf-query -c xfce4-desktop -p /backdrop/screen8/monitor0/image-path)
    FP8M1=$(xfconf-query -c xfce4-desktop -p /backdrop/screen8/monitor1/image-path)
    FP8M2=$(xfconf-query -c xfce4-desktop -p /backdrop/screen8/monitor2/image-path)
    FP8M3=$(xfconf-query -c xfce4-desktop -p /backdrop/screen8/monitor3/image-path)
    FP8M4=$(xfconf-query -c xfce4-desktop -p /backdrop/screen8/monitor4/image-path)
    FP8M5=$(xfconf-query -c xfce4-desktop -p /backdrop/screen8/monitor5/image-path) 
    FP8M6=$(xfconf-query -c xfce4-desktop -p /backdrop/screen8/monitor6/image-path)
    FP8M7=$(xfconf-query -c xfce4-desktop -p /backdrop/screen8/monitor7/image-path)
    FP8M8=$(xfconf-query -c xfce4-desktop -p /backdrop/screen8/monitor8/image-path)
    FP8M9=$(xfconf-query -c xfce4-desktop -p /backdrop/screen8/monitor9/image-path) 
    FP9M0=$(xfconf-query -c xfce4-desktop -p /backdrop/screen9/monitor0/image-path)
    FP9M1=$(xfconf-query -c xfce4-desktop -p /backdrop/screen9/monitor1/image-path)
    FP9M2=$(xfconf-query -c xfce4-desktop -p /backdrop/screen9/monitor2/image-path)
    FP9M3=$(xfconf-query -c xfce4-desktop -p /backdrop/screen9/monitor3/image-path)
    FP9M4=$(xfconf-query -c xfce4-desktop -p /backdrop/screen9/monitor4/image-path)
    FP9M5=$(xfconf-query -c xfce4-desktop -p /backdrop/screen9/monitor5/image-path) 
    FP9M6=$(xfconf-query -c xfce4-desktop -p /backdrop/screen9/monitor6/image-path)
    FP9M7=$(xfconf-query -c xfce4-desktop -p /backdrop/screen9/monitor7/image-path)
    FP9M8=$(xfconf-query -c xfce4-desktop -p /backdrop/screen9/monitor8/image-path)
    FP9M9=$(xfconf-query -c xfce4-desktop -p /backdrop/screen9/monitor9/image-path) 

# Agregar if con la condicion a la inversa
# Para los Fondos de Pantalla
# Si por ejemplo la variable $FP0M0 = "" , then no hagas nada : else "has algo"

# Panel(es)
# Todos del 1 al 9 
#
#
# $ xfconf-query -c xfce4-panel -p /panels/panel-{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9} -l -v
#
# Aqui se viene el otro lio , que creo que tendre que solucionar 1 por 1
# como los fondos de pantallas de arriba
#
#
    # 1 - Opacidad del Panel :
    # Canal : Panel ; Propiedad 1 : /panels/panel-1/background-alpha
    #xfconf-query -c xfce4-panel -p /panels/panel-{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9}/background-alpha
    # Forma Facil   (Puede Fallar)  -> P1VBA=$(xfconf-query -c xfce4-panel -p /panels/panel-1/background-alpha)
    # Forma Dificil (No Falla)  -> P1VBA=$(xfconf-query -c xfce4-panel -p /panels/panel-1/background-alpha -l -v | awk -F'/' '/^/ { print $4 }' | sed 's/[background]*.//' | sed 's/[-alpha]*.//')

    P1VBA=$(xfconf-query -c xfce4-panel -p /panels/panel-1/background-alpha -l -v | awk -F'/' '/^/ { print $4 }' | sed 's/[background]*.//' | sed 's/[-alpha]*.//') 
    P2VBA=$(xfconf-query -c xfce4-panel -p /panels/panel-2/background-alpha -l -v | awk -F'/' '/^/ { print $4 }' | sed 's/[background]*.//' | sed 's/[-alpha]*.//') 
    P3VBA=$(xfconf-query -c xfce4-panel -p /panels/panel-3/background-alpha -l -v | awk -F'/' '/^/ { print $4 }' | sed 's/[background]*.//' | sed 's/[-alpha]*.//') 

    #2 - Estilo del Fondo del Panel
    # Canal : Panel ; Propiedad 2 : /panels/panel-1/background-style
    #xfconf-query -c xfce4-panel -p /panels/panel-{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9}/background-style
    # Forma Facil   (Puede Fallar)  -> P1VBS=$(xfconf-query -c xfce4-panel -p /panels/panel-1/background-style)
    # Forma Dificil (No Falla)  -> P1VBS=$(xfconf-query -c xfce4-panel -p /panels/panel-1/background-style -l -v | awk -F'/' '/^/ { print $4 }' | sed 's/[background]*.//' | sed 's/[-style]*.//')

    P1VBS=$(xfconf-query -c xfce4-panel -p /panels/panel-1/background-style -l -v | awk -F'/' '/^/ { print $4 }' | sed 's/[background]*.//' | sed 's/[-style]*.//')
    P2VBS=$(xfconf-query -c xfce4-panel -p /panels/panel-2/background-style -l -v | awk -F'/' '/^/ { print $4 }' | sed 's/[background]*.//' | sed 's/[-style]*.//')
    P3VBS=$(xfconf-query -c xfce4-panel -p /panels/panel-3/background-style -l -v | awk -F'/' '/^/ { print $4 }' | sed 's/[background]*.//' | sed 's/[-style]*.//')

    #3 - Opacidad al tener el puntero del raton en el panel
    # Canal : Panel ; Propiedad 3 : /panels/panel-1/enter-opacity
    #xfconf-query -c xfce4-panel -p /panels/panel-{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9}/enter-opacity
    # Forma Facil   (Puede Fallar)  -> P1VEO=$(xfconf-query -c xfce4-panel -p /panels/panel-1/enter-opacity)
    # Forma Dificil (No Falla)  -> P1VEO=$(xfconf-query -c xfce4-panel -p /panels/panel-1/enter-opacity -l -v | awk -F'/' '/^/ { print $4 }' | sed 's/[enter]*.//' | sed 's/[-opacity]*.//')

    P1VEO=$(xfconf-query -c xfce4-panel -p /panels/panel-1/enter-opacity -l -v | awk -F'/' '/^/ { print $4 }' | sed 's/[enter]*.//' | sed 's/[-opacity]*.//')
    P2VEO=$(xfconf-query -c xfce4-panel -p /panels/panel-2/enter-opacity -l -v | awk -F'/' '/^/ { print $4 }' | sed 's/[enter]*.//' | sed 's/[-opacity]*.//')
    P3VEO=$(xfconf-query -c xfce4-panel -p /panels/panel-3/enter-opacity -l -v | awk -F'/' '/^/ { print $4 }' | sed 's/[enter]*.//' | sed 's/[-opacity]*.//')
    P4VEO=$(xfconf-query -c xfce4-panel -p /panels/panel-4/enter-opacity -l -v | awk -F'/' '/^/ { print $4 }' | sed 's/[enter]*.//' | sed 's/[-opacity]*.//')
    P5VEO=$(xfconf-query -c xfce4-panel -p /panels/panel-5/enter-opacity -l -v | awk -F'/' '/^/ { print $4 }' | sed 's/[enter]*.//' | sed 's/[-opacity]*.//')
    P6VEO=$(xfconf-query -c xfce4-panel -p /panels/panel-6/enter-opacity -l -v | awk -F'/' '/^/ { print $4 }' | sed 's/[enter]*.//' | sed 's/[-opacity]*.//')
    P7VEO=$(xfconf-query -c xfce4-panel -p /panels/panel-7/enter-opacity -l -v | awk -F'/' '/^/ { print $4 }' | sed 's/[enter]*.//' | sed 's/[-opacity]*.//')
    P8VEO=$(xfconf-query -c xfce4-panel -p /panels/panel-8/enter-opacity -l -v | awk -F'/' '/^/ { print $4 }' | sed 's/[enter]*.//' | sed 's/[-opacity]*.//')
    P9VEO=$(xfconf-query -c xfce4-panel -p /panels/panel-9/enter-opacity -l -v | awk -F'/' '/^/ { print $4 }' | sed 's/[enter]*.//' | sed 's/[-opacity]*.//')

    #4 - Opacidad al no tener el puntero del raton en el panel
    # Canal : Panel ; Propiedad 4 : /panels/panel-?/leave-opacity
    #xfconf-query -c xfce4-panel -p /panels/panel-{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9}/leave-opacity
    # Forma Facil   (Puede Fallar)  -> P1VLO=$(xfconf-query -c xfce4-panel -p /panels/panel-1/leave-opacity)
    # Forma Dificil (No Falla)  -> P1VLO=$(xfconf-query -c xfce4-panel -p /panels/panel-1/leave-opacity #-l -v | awk -F'/' '/^/ { print $4 }' | sed 's/[leave]*.//' | sed 's/[-opacity]*.//')

    P1VLO=$(xfconf-query -c xfce4-panel -p /panels/panel-1/leave-opacity -l -v | awk -F'/' '/^/ { print $4 }' | sed 's/[leave]*.//' | sed 's/[-opacity]*.//')
    P2VLO=$(xfconf-query -c xfce4-panel -p /panels/panel-2/leave-opacity -l -v | awk -F'/' '/^/ { print $4 }' | sed 's/[leave]*.//' | sed 's/[-opacity]*.//')
    P3VLO=$(xfconf-query -c xfce4-panel -p /panels/panel-3/leave-opacity -l -v | awk -F'/' '/^/ { print $4 }' | sed 's/[leave]*.//' | sed 's/[-opacity]*.//')
    P4VLO=$(xfconf-query -c xfce4-panel -p /panels/panel-4/leave-opacity -l -v | awk -F'/' '/^/ { print $4 }' | sed 's/[leave]*.//' | sed 's/[-opacity]*.//')
    P5VLO=$(xfconf-query -c xfce4-panel -p /panels/panel-5/leave-opacity -l -v | awk -F'/' '/^/ { print $4 }' | sed 's/[leave]*.//' | sed 's/[-opacity]*.//')
    P6VLO=$(xfconf-query -c xfce4-panel -p /panels/panel-6/leave-opacity -l -v | awk -F'/' '/^/ { print $4 }' | sed 's/[leave]*.//' | sed 's/[-opacity]*.//')
    P7VLO=$(xfconf-query -c xfce4-panel -p /panels/panel-7/leave-opacity -l -v | awk -F'/' '/^/ { print $4 }' | sed 's/[leave]*.//' | sed 's/[-opacity]*.//')
    P8VLO=$(xfconf-query -c xfce4-panel -p /panels/panel-8/leave-opacity -l -v | awk -F'/' '/^/ { print $4 }' | sed 's/[leave]*.//' | sed 's/[-opacity]*.//')
    P9VLO=$(xfconf-query -c xfce4-panel -p /panels/panel-9/leave-opacity -l -v | awk -F'/' '/^/ { print $4 }' | sed 's/[leave]*.//' | sed 's/[-opacity]*.//')

    #5 - longitud de [el/los] panel[es] 
    # Canal : Panel ; Propiedad 5 : (/panels/panel-?/length)
    #xfconf-query -c xfce4-panel -p /panels/panel-{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9}/length
    # Forma Facil   (Puede Fallar)  -> P1VLL=$(xfconf-query -c xfce4-panel -p /panels/panel-1/length)
    # Forma Dificil (No Falla)  -> P1VLL=$(xfconf-query -c xfce4-panel -p /panels/panel-1/length -l -v | awk -F'/' '/^/ { print $4 }' | sed 's/[length]*.//')

    P1VLL=$(xfconf-query -c xfce4-panel -p /panels/panel-1/length -l -v | awk -F'/' '/^/ { print $4 }' | sed 's/[length]*.//')
    P2VLL=$(xfconf-query -c xfce4-panel -p /panels/panel-2/length -l -v | awk -F'/' '/^/ { print $4 }' | sed 's/[length]*.//')
    P3VLL=$(xfconf-query -c xfce4-panel -p /panels/panel-3/length -l -v | awk -F'/' '/^/ { print $4 }' | sed 's/[length]*.//')
    P4VLL=$(xfconf-query -c xfce4-panel -p /panels/panel-4/length -l -v | awk -F'/' '/^/ { print $4 }' | sed 's/[length]*.//')
    P5VLL=$(xfconf-query -c xfce4-panel -p /panels/panel-5/length -l -v | awk -F'/' '/^/ { print $4 }' | sed 's/[length]*.//')
    P6VLL=$(xfconf-query -c xfce4-panel -p /panels/panel-6/length -l -v | awk -F'/' '/^/ { print $4 }' | sed 's/[length]*.//')
    P7VLL=$(xfconf-query -c xfce4-panel -p /panels/panel-7/length -l -v | awk -F'/' '/^/ { print $4 }' | sed 's/[length]*.//')
    P8VLL=$(xfconf-query -c xfce4-panel -p /panels/panel-8/length -l -v | awk -F'/' '/^/ { print $4 }' | sed 's/[length]*.//')
    P9VLL=$(xfconf-query -c xfce4-panel -p /panels/panel-9/length -l -v | awk -F'/' '/^/ { print $4 }' | sed 's/[length]*.//')


    #6 - Complementos "ids" ??? : Esto va a estar jodido :S
    # Canal : Panel ; Propiedad 6 : (/panels/panel-?/plugin-ids)
    xfconf-query -c xfce4-panel -p /panels/panel-{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9}/plugin-ids












    #7 - Posicion de [el/los] panel[es]
    # Canal : Panel ; Propiedad 7 : (/panels/panel-?/position)
    #xfconf-query -c xfce4-panel -p /panels/panel-{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9}/position
    # Forma Facil   (Puede Fallar)  -> P1VPO=$(xfconf-query -c xfce4-panel -p /panels/panel-1/position)
    # Forma Dificil (No Falla)  -> P1VPO=$(xfconf-query -c xfce4-panel -p /panels/panel-1/position -l -v | awk -F'/' '/^/ { print $4 }' | sed 's/[position]*.//')

    P1VPO=$(xfconf-query -c xfce4-panel -p /panels/panel-1/position -l -v | awk -F'/' '/^/ { print $4 }' | sed 's/[position]*.//')
    P2VPO=$(xfconf-query -c xfce4-panel -p /panels/panel-1/position -l -v | awk -F'/' '/^/ { print $4 }' | sed 's/[position]*.//')
    P3VPO=$(xfconf-query -c xfce4-panel -p /panels/panel-1/position -l -v | awk -F'/' '/^/ { print $4 }' | sed 's/[position]*.//')
    P4VPO=$(xfconf-query -c xfce4-panel -p /panels/panel-1/position -l -v | awk -F'/' '/^/ { print $4 }' | sed 's/[position]*.//')
    P5VPO=$(xfconf-query -c xfce4-panel -p /panels/panel-1/position -l -v | awk -F'/' '/^/ { print $4 }' | sed 's/[position]*.//')
    P6VPO=$(xfconf-query -c xfce4-panel -p /panels/panel-1/position -l -v | awk -F'/' '/^/ { print $4 }' | sed 's/[position]*.//')
    P7VPO=$(xfconf-query -c xfce4-panel -p /panels/panel-1/position -l -v | awk -F'/' '/^/ { print $4 }' | sed 's/[position]*.//')
    P8VPO=$(xfconf-query -c xfce4-panel -p /panels/panel-1/position -l -v | awk -F'/' '/^/ { print $4 }' | sed 's/[position]*.//')
    P9VPO=$(xfconf-query -c xfce4-panel -p /panels/panel-1/position -l -v | awk -F'/' '/^/ { print $4 }' | sed 's/[position]*.//')

    #8 - Bloqueado en su posicion
    # Canal : Panel ; Propiedad 8 : (/panels/panel-?/position-locked)
    #xfconf-query -c xfce4-panel -p /panels/panel-{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9}/position-locked
    # Forma Facil   (Puede Fallar)  -> P1VPL=$(xfconf-query -c xfce4-panel -p /panels/panel-1/position-locked)
    # Forma Dificil (No Falla)  -> P1VPL=$(xfconf-query -c xfce4-panel -p /panels/panel-1/position-locked -l -v | awk -F'/' '/^/ { print $4 }' | sed 's/[position]*.//' | sed 's/[-locked]*.//')

    P1VPL=$(xfconf-query -c xfce4-panel -p /panels/panel-1/position-locked -l -v | awk -F'/' '/^/ { print $4 }' | sed 's/[position]*.//' | sed 's/[-locked]*.//')
    P2VPL=$(xfconf-query -c xfce4-panel -p /panels/panel-2/position-locked -l -v | awk -F'/' '/^/ { print $4 }' | sed 's/[position]*.//' | sed 's/[-locked]*.//')
    P3VPL=$(xfconf-query -c xfce4-panel -p /panels/panel-3/position-locked -l -v | awk -F'/' '/^/ { print $4 }' | sed 's/[position]*.//' | sed 's/[-locked]*.//')

    #9 - Tamaños : 
    # Canal : Panel ; Propiedad 9 : (/panels/panel-?/size)
    # Forma Facil   (Puede Fallar)  -> P1VOS=$(xfconf-query -c xfce4-panel -p /panels/panel-1/size)
    # Forma Dificil (No Falla)  -> P1VOS=$(xfconf-query -c xfce4-panel -p /panels/panel-1/size -l -v | awk -F'/' '/^/ { print $4 }' | sed 's/[size]*.//')

    P1VOS=$(xfconf-query -c xfce4-panel -p /panels/panel-1/size -l -v | awk -F'/' '/^/ { print $4 }' | sed 's/[size]*.//')
    P2VOS=$(xfconf-query -c xfce4-panel -p /panels/panel-2/size -l -v | awk -F'/' '/^/ { print $4 }' | sed 's/[size]*.//')
    P3VOS=$(xfconf-query -c xfce4-panel -p /panels/panel-3/size -l -v | awk -F'/' '/^/ { print $4 }' | sed 's/[size]*.//')
    P4VOS=$(xfconf-query -c xfce4-panel -p /panels/panel-4/size -l -v | awk -F'/' '/^/ { print $4 }' | sed 's/[size]*.//')
    P5VOS=$(xfconf-query -c xfce4-panel -p /panels/panel-5/size -l -v | awk -F'/' '/^/ { print $4 }' | sed 's/[size]*.//')
    P6VOS=$(xfconf-query -c xfce4-panel -p /panels/panel-6/size -l -v | awk -F'/' '/^/ { print $4 }' | sed 's/[size]*.//')
    P7VOS=$(xfconf-query -c xfce4-panel -p /panels/panel-7/size -l -v | awk -F'/' '/^/ { print $4 }' | sed 's/[size]*.//')
    P8VOS=$(xfconf-query -c xfce4-panel -p /panels/panel-8/size -l -v | awk -F'/' '/^/ { print $4 }' | sed 's/[size]*.//')
    P9VOS=$(xfconf-query -c xfce4-panel -p /panels/panel-9/size -l -v | awk -F'/' '/^/ { print $4 }' | sed 's/[size]*.//')

fi
```

The actual problem is with the "Panel" & "plugin-ids":

```
$ xfconf-query -c xfce4-panel -p /panels/panel-1/plugin-ids -v
El valor es un vector con 6 elementos:

1
34
15
24
27
2
```

I can save it in a varible, for example with:

```
TESTVAR=$(xfconf-query -c xfce4-panel -p /panels/panel-1/plugin-ids -v)
```

But I really don't know how to apply that values, direct from Bash script from CLI or if I launch the script for the graphic session, and make it work.

For example, I need save that values, after, if I change the theme, and the plugins inside that panel.

How can I restore from CLI using the `$TESTVAR`, values?

And the another thing, can someone tell me how I can improve the script, to be more advanced, and not make too much variables for the same like:

```
FP0M0=$(xfconf-query -c xfce4-desktop -p /backdrop/screen0/monitor0/image-path)
FP0M1=$(xfconf-query -c xfce4-desktop -p /backdrop/screen0/monitor1/image-path)
FP1M0=$(xfconf-query -c xfce4-desktop -p /backdrop/screen1/monitor0/image-path)
FP1M1=$(xfconf-query -c xfce4-desktop -p /backdrop/screen0/monitor1/image-path)
```

That it's the same, the unique thing, the numbers in "screen" are different, like in "monitor",  I can transform that in a advance variable using substitutions, and save the values for use after for restore theme from make it script?

Comment: What's up with the double shebang?!

Comment: Not that I quite get your question, but a few general tips: Read `man bash`, especially the ‘Arrays’ section. Use http://www.shellcheck.net . Use `$()` instead of `\`\``. Use `set -e`. Use `set -x` for debugging. Put common tasks in functions.

Comment: i ever use shellcheck.net , after i complete the script , for check all . in all variables i use "VariableName=$(commads arguments and parameters) , ok im going to check the 'Arrays' :) , someone tellme use "Arrays" but never specify me what class of Arrays

Comment: You have provided a lot of code here, please consider revising your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)